# Expected Value and mean of random variable

Tags: expected-value

If random variable a and random variable b and they have the same distribution and are independent, is it true that E[˜a˜b] =E [˜a]^2?

Comment: Have you tried any examples? Doing so should have answered your question pretty quickly.

Comment: What is meant by "˜a˜b" and "˜b" exactly?